# Is there an issue with tSCPFileExists component in Talend

Tags: java, talend

I'm using the component tSCPFileExists of talend to check either my file which is in a remote server exists or not. But I'm getting this error

```
"'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command "
```

It seems that talend has a problem with this component !

[image]
Any idea ? Thank u for help

this the configuration of my tSCPFileExists component

[image]

Comment: What is the OS of the remote server ?

Comment: it is windows server

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the configuration of tSCPFileExists_1 ?

Comment: @Corentin I added it

Comment: @amani92, do you have an scp client installed on your windows server ? can you run an scp command on the remote machine please ?

Comment: @54l3d I think that the scp client should be installed on my own machine to run the command in the server not in the server, isn'it ?

Comment: @amani92 It shold be installed for both, its a client server protocol.

Comment: @54l3d I just installed WinSCP now in my machine and I can run commands very well through it in the remote server . (the ls command works fine)

Comment: but it's illogical ! on the one hand, the ls command works fine and on the other hand, I get "'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command " when using tSCPFileExists !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132212/discussion-between-54l3d-and-amani92).

Answer (score 3):

I took a look on the source code generated by Talend, here it is :

```
StringBuilder command_tSCPFileExists_1 = new StringBuilder();
                command_tSCPFileExists_1.append("ls \"").append("C:/")
                        .append("/").append("file.tst").append("\"");
                globalMap.put("tSCPFileExists_1_FILENAME", "file.tst");
```

Hence Talend execute `ls` command on the remote machine, and obviously it works on Linux based machines and not a windows ones.

And i think it make sense because SCP protocol is not supported natively by Windows, see this post [here](https://superuser.com/q/267214).

Alternatively, you can use [tFTPFileExist](https://help.talend.com/display/ComposantsTalendOpenStudioGuidedereference60FR/tFTPFileExist) which is supported by Windows and Linux.

Comment: I'm using an scp connection so i can't use tFTPFileExist

Comment: Try to use `SFTP` connection with the same connection parameters

Comment: Use `SFTP` support in the component, port 22 and same user / password